# How can make all my user control dependency values load before they control accesses their values?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

When I call this custom control, I have to put the attribute values in the **correct order** since the third dependency property (**ItemTypeIdCode**) accesses the values of the first two (**KeyField, ValueField**) to look up data in the database, and if they come after the first attribute, then their values are empty.

```
<controls:DropDown x:Name="TheItemTypes" 
  KeyField="idCode" ValueField="title" 
  ItemTypeIdCode="itemTypes" 
  Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0 0 0 5"/>
```

**How can I make the order of my user control attributes arbitrary?** i.e. so that they all load their values first before any of them register as changed?

Here is the code for my user control:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TestApp.DataLayer;

namespace TestApp.Controls
{
    public partial class DropDown : DependencyComboBox
    {
        #region DependencyProperty: ItemTypeIdCode
        public string ItemTypeIdCode
        {
            get
            {
                if (GetValue(ItemTypeIdCodeProperty) != null)
                    return GetValue(ItemTypeIdCodeProperty).ToString();
                else
                    return "";
            }
            set { SetValue(ItemTypeIdCodeProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTypeIdCodeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ItemTypeIdCode", typeof(string), typeof(DropDown),
                new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnItemTypeIdCodePropertyChanged));

        private static void OnItemTypeIdCodePropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DropDown dropDown = dependencyObject as DropDown;
            dropDown.OnPropertyChanged("ItemTypeIdCode");
            dropDown.OnItemTypeIdCodePropertyChanged(e);
        }

        private void OnItemTypeIdCodePropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            Items.Clear();
            foreach (var kvp in Datasource.GetInstance().GetKeyValues(ItemTypeIdCode + "(" + KeyField + "," + ValueField + "); all; orderby displayOrder"))
            {
                Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
            }
            this.SelectedIndex = 0;

        }
        #endregion


        #region DependencyProperty: KeyField
        public string KeyField
        {
            get
            {
                if (GetValue(KeyFieldProperty) != null)
                    return GetValue(KeyFieldProperty).ToString();
                else
                    return "";
            }
            set { SetValue(KeyFieldProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty KeyFieldProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("KeyField", typeof(string), typeof(DropDown),
                new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnKeyFieldPropertyChanged));

        private static void OnKeyFieldPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DropDown dropDown = dependencyObject as DropDown;
            dropDown.OnPropertyChanged("KeyField");
            dropDown.OnKeyFieldPropertyChanged(e);
        }

        private void OnKeyFieldPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
        #endregion

        #region DependencyProperty: ValueField
        public string ValueField
        {
            get
            {
                if (GetValue(ValueFieldProperty) != null)
                    return GetValue(ValueFieldProperty).ToString();
                else
                    return "";
            }
            set { SetValue(ValueFieldProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueFieldProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ValueField", typeof(string), typeof(DropDown),
                new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnValueFieldPropertyChanged));

        private static void OnValueFieldPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DropDown dropDown = dependencyObject as DropDown;
            dropDown.OnPropertyChanged("ValueField");
            dropDown.OnValueFieldPropertyChanged(e);
        }

        private void OnValueFieldPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
        #endregion

        public DropDown()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize `Items` only when all properties are set :

```
    private void InitItems()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ItemTypeIdCode) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(KeyField) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ValueField))
        {

            Items.Clear();
            foreach (var kvp in Datasource.GetInstance().GetKeyValues(ItemTypeIdCode + "(" + KeyField + "," + ValueField + "); all; orderby displayOrder"))
            {
                Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
            }
            this.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    private void OnItemTypeIdCodePropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        InitItems();
    }

    private static void OnKeyFieldPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DropDown dropDown = dependencyObject as DropDown;
        dropDown.InitItems();
        dropDown.OnPropertyChanged("KeyField");
        dropDown.OnKeyFieldPropertyChanged(e);
    }

    private static void OnValueFieldPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DropDown dropDown = dependencyObject as DropDown;
        dropDown.InitItems();
        dropDown.OnPropertyChanged("ValueField");
        dropDown.OnValueFieldPropertyChanged(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Any way you can do the setup processing in the Load event instead of the property accessors? Then all the needed properties will be set by load time.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed you're asking about WPF. I don't know if it has the same kind of events.